# how to change the recipient of forwarded email

Tags: email, gmail

I have an email inbox called A@xyz.com

My client sends an email to that address but I decide that it is not my job to respond to that so I send it to my coworker B@xyz.com

I want to make it so when B responds to that forwarded email it send the message to my client as if it was to B all along. And when my client want to respond to that email it sends the response directly to B.

I have tried doing it through forwading but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way or is it not possible at all?

Comment: There's reply to, or delegation. Are these personal accounts or business accounts? If business, you'll be able to set up delegation and such by asking your admins.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Reply to:** address to the originator rather than yourself.
Details depend on email client.

[image]